# Proofs of Dirichlet's unit theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for "different" proofs of Dirichlet's unit theorem.

I know of

Neukirch Algebraic Number Theory (Chapter 1)

and

Keith Conrad's write-up https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/unittheorem.pdf

I would say that these two proofs are essentially the same (as they rely on Minkowski's geometry of numbers).

Are there other *really* different proofs of Dirichlet's unit theorem?

Comment: Can you tell us your background?  For a number field $K$, the unit theorem for $K$ and finiteness of the class group of $K$ are together equivalent to compactness of $J_K^1/K^\times$, where $J_K^1$ is the group of ideles of $K$ with idellic norm 1, and that compactness can be proved first.  See Theorem 5.3 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/676Page/handouts/compactidele.pdf.  Note this is based on a replacement for Minkowski's lemma that uses the adeles of $K$ (see Section 2).

Comment: Dirichlet proved his unit theorem (for unit groups of orders of the form $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$) using the pigeonhole principle about 45 years before Minkowski's convex body theorem, so you could look up a proof of the unit theorem based on the pigeonhole principle: see Koch's *Number Theory: Algebraic Numbers and Functions*.  This is mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of section 3 of your 2nd link.